# Cant get the site out of maintence mode

Tags: maintenance-mode

I am using Drupal 7.
I just started creating a new drupal site. Instead of downloading all of the necessary contributed modules, I copied them from a different test site I had made recently. There were a few modules which needed to be updated, so I put the site in maintenance mode, deleted those module folders, pasted in the new ones, ran the update script and now I have no errors. However, now it still says "Operating in Maintenance mode - Go Online", and clicking "Go Online" brings me back to the maintenance configuration page, but I remain in Maintenance Mode! I cleared all caches and nothing helped!
I could just restart everything from scratch, but I would like to understand this issue.

I'm not sure if this make a difference, but originally when I installed the drupal database, I used a previously created database which had only one table (non-drupal) which I deleted before installing the drupal database tables. Should this have effected anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your description of what you do is accurate, the problem is simple to solve.

Clicking "Go online" is only the first step required to take your site out of maintenance mode.  You *also* need to remove the tick from the box to the left of "Put site into maintenance mode", and then click "Save configuration".

However, if you go through all these steps, and it still fails, you need to update your question to accurately descibe what you do, and we'll take it from there.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I tried that but I guess I didn't.